# How to convert a Tuple of Tuples to a Map

Tags: scala

I have a `Tuple` of `Tuple`s and need to convert it to a `Map`. For example

```
(("a", 3), ("b", 1), ("c", 7), ..., ("z", 10))
```

should result in the `Map`

```
Map("a" -> 3, "b" -> 1, ..., "z" -> 10)
```

What are the ways to do this in Scala?

Comment: But don’t expect a `Tuple26` from `'a'` to `'z'` to compile, though…

Comment: Tuples are not lists. They're not even HLists. They're really only suitable when a few values of unrelated types come together for incidental reasons. Specifically, when those types are not otherwise related and the aggregation does not really represent a key abstraction in your program. Otherwise, define a real class to represent that aggregation and endow it with the ability to perform the transformations you require upon those aggregated values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
scala> tuples
res0: ((String, Int), (String, Int), (String, Int)) = ((a,3),(b,1),(c,7))


scala> tuples.productIterator.map{case (a,b)=> (a -> b)}.toMap
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Any,Any] = Map(a -> 3, b -> 1, c -> 7)


scala> res1("a")
res2: Any = 3

scala> res1("b")
res3: Any = 1

scala> res1("c")
res4: Any = 7
```

Comment: what if I want to get a Map[String, Int] instead of Map[Any, Any]?

Comment: `productIterator` returns an iterator of `Any` so you can try to convert the `Any` types to `String` and `Int` respectively. This works `tuples.productIterator.map{case (a,b)=> (a.toString -> new Integer(b.toString))}.toMap` but I suspect there are other ways.

Comment: In that case you can add the type to match on the `case`, like: `tuples.productIterator.map{ case (a:String, b:Int) => (a,b) }.toMap`

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to pull a dependency into your project, this kind of typelevel things are what [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) is good for:

```
> shapeless-core/console
[warn] Credentials file /home/folone/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
[info] Compiling 24 Scala sources to /home/folone/workspace/shapeless/core/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.0-20130205-141957-132e09fc2e (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_17).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import shapeless._
import shapeless._

scala> import Tuples._
import Tuples._

scala> val tuples = (("a", 3), ("b", 1), ("c", 7), ("z", 10))
tuples: ((String, Int), (String, Int), (String, Int), (String, Int)) = ((a,3),(b,1),(c,7),(z,10))

scala> tuples.hlisted.toList.toMap
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 3, b -> 1, c -> 7, z -> 10)
```

In contrast to the other solutions, all the types are checked at compile time. So, this won't compile:

```
scala> val tuples = (("a", 3), ("b", 1), ("c", 7), ("z", "hello"))
tuples: ((String, Int), (String, Int), (String, Int), (String, String)) = ((a,3),(b,1),(c,7),(z,hello))

scala> tuples.hlisted.toList.toMap
<console>:15: error: could not find implicit value for parameter toList: shapeless.ToList[shapeless.::[(String, Int),shapeless.::[(String, Int),shapeless.::[(String, Int),shapeless.::[(String, String),shapeless.HNil]]]],Lub]
              tuples.hlisted.toList.toMap
                             ^
```

Here's [@milessabin's talk](http://youtu.be/GDbNxL8bqkY) at nescala 2012, including some info on `HList`s. And if you'll like it, [here's](http://youtu.be/9w1PDnD5mPc) the latest shapeless hotness from this year.

Answer (score 1):

As a first step, for arbitrary tuples `t` (actually instances of `scala.Product`) you can use `t.productIterator` to obtain an `Iterator[Any]` over its components.

Then, to get a map you can do the following:

```
t.productIterator.asInstanceOf[Iterator[(String, Int)]].toMap
```

*Remark*: It seems a bit strange to use a tuple in your case, since the types of the arguments are homogeneous. Why not use a `List[(String, Int)]` like

```
List(("a", 3), ("b", 1), ("c", 7), ..., ("z", 10))
```

Comment: I got Iterator[Any] exactly as you said. But how can I take out the componenets from Any? Note it is not a Tuple any more.

Answer (score 1):

Two most concise solutions:

```
scala> tuples
res50: ((String, Int), (String, Int), (String, Int)) = ((a,3),(b,1),(c,7))

scala> tuples.productIterator.map{case t: (String, Int) => t}.toMap
res51: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 3, b -> 1, c -> 7)

scala> tuples.productIterator.map(_.asInstanceOf[(String, Int)]).toMap
res54: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 3, b -> 1, c -> 7)
```